# Unconditional Longitudinal/Multilevel Modeling

Tags: modeling, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, biostatistics

My research question is how does age, sex, race, and/or tumor type affect concentration of an enzyme in the blood over a 2 year period. I am looking at creating an unconditional longitudinal model (longitudinal multilevel model) following the steps of 1) establishing an unconditional means model 2) unconditional growth model, then finally a 3) conditional growth model.

I was looking at an example online of unconditional longitudinal modeling that looked at how job performance is affected by training duration over 4 time points. In the example, not only was job performance quantified but also job satisfaction at each time point. The conditional growth model in the example factored in job satisfaction in its multilevel analysis (Ultimate question: does time and job satisfaction affect job performance longitudinally?). Job satisfaction while being the independent variable is not a fixed value like race/sex which innately are not values that can change like job satisfaction.

Therefore, my question is can age, sex, race, and tumor type be considered my predictive values(IV) if they innately are fixed values that do not change within this model?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

"Unconditional" modeling sounds like an example of using GEE rather than a mixed effects model. You should absolutely include the so called "between-cluster" effects to reduce unmeasured dependence between groups, to increase the power of your analysis, and to bridge the gap between "unconditional" and "conditional" effects.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I ran the analysis and the log-lik value to evaluate the fit quality went from -730 => -723 => -713 when using the unconditional means model => unconditional growth model => conditional growth model . While a clear drop at each stage of modeling, it seems like the log-like value is still not very close to 0, which I believe means the fit of the data is still poor. Do you think the results are still valid in being used for processing in this model analysis? Again, thank you so much!!

Comment: @JJMM1234 you're clearly not using GEE because a GEE has no log likelihood. I'll assume you're using mixed model for conditional, and marginal (likelihood based) model for unconditional. Anyway, "conditioning" will always improve likelihood because it's the same as adding a parameter. Same as considering a "growth" model over a stationary/exchangeable correlation matrix. You're just adding parameters. I didn't think this was a model selection problem, so why are you fitting a bunch of different models?